# Specify 'CONTENT_TYPE' to 'application/json' in Ember.$.post()

Tags: jquery, ember.js

Hi so the server I am pinging accepts json objects and sends back json is well, when I was using just ajax I would just use `$.ajax()` and specify `content_type` to `application/json`.

But since Ember uses `$.post()` is there a work around for specifying `content_type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `$.post` and `$.get` methods use `$.ajax` internally like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url: url,
   type: method,
   dataType: type,
   data: data,
   success: callback
});
```

So you can not specify `content-Type` for request directly. However, [`$.ajaxOptions`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) could be used to specify common options for all outgoing requests, like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  contentType: "application/json"
})
```